# Python 3 tkinter insert file contents into a text box

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter, textbox

Okay so I have done about 10 days of searching and I caved in so I'm turning to the community for help. 
I am using python 3.6 and tkinter as a user interface. 
The basic's of what I'm trying to accomplish is that I have a file that I open and search for a word within the file and insert all the lines that word falls on. 
My issue is that its only inserting the first line it finds and I need it to insert all the lines it finds. Sorry for wet coding I'll dry it up once I have functionality later

here's a sample of my code (it's not the full thing but it should give you more than enough info about what I'm trying to accomplish):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
# i added all my imports that this class use's in case you guys think they could pose a problem but they shouldn't be a issue

class EXAMPLEapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default = "dlm64.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Example.")
        self.FILE_MENU_BAR()
        self.minsize(width = 360, height = 200)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.frames = {}
        for FRAME in (SearchPage):
            frame = FRAME(container, self)
            self.frames[FRAME] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(SearchPage)
    def FILE_MENU_BAR(self):
        #File
        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        self.configure(menu = self.menubar)
        File_Menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = False)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = File_Menu)
        File_Menu.add_command(label = "EXIT" , command = self.File_EXIT)
        # Edit Menu
        Edit_Menu = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff = False)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu = Edit_Menu)
        Edit_Menu.add_command(label = "cut", underline = 2, command = self.Edit_Cut)
        Edit_Menu.add_command(label = "copy", underline = 0, command = self.Edit_Copy)  
    def File_EXIT(self):
        sys.exit(0)
    def Edit_Cut(self):
        print("CUT")
    def Edit_Copy(self):
        print("COPY")
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class SearchPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Search Inventory", font = ("Helvetica", 20, 'bold', 'underline'))
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew", pady = (0,0), padx = (0,0))
        button0 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Inventory Search")
        button0.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))     
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "New Inventory", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(CreatePage))
        button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Edit Invetory", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(EditPage))
        button2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))         
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Ship", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(ShipPage))
        button3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Graph", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PlotPage))
        button4.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))

        DATE_VAR = tk.StringVar()
        def DATE_SEARCH():
            USER_TEXT = DATE_VAR.get()
            with open('SAMPLE.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
                for line in searchfile:
                    if USER_TEXT == '':
                        LABEL = tk.Text(self, width = 30, height = 2, wrap = tk.WORD, foreground = 'red')
                        LABEL.grid(row = 6, column = 3, sticky = "nsew", pady = (0,0), padx = (20,0))
                        LABEL.insert(1.0, "PLEASE ENTER A VALUE")
                        LABEL.configure(state = 'disabled')
                        break
                    elif USER_TEXT in line:
                        LABEL = tk.Text(self, width = 100, height = 4, wrap = tk.WORD)
                        LABEL.grid(row = 6, column = 3, sticky = "e", pady = (0,0), padx = (20,0))
                        LABEL.insert(1.0, line)
                        LABEL.configure(state = 'disabled')
                        ScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
                        ScrollBar.config(command = LABEL.yview)
                        LABEL.config(yscrollcommand = ScrollBar.set)
                        ScrollBar.grid(row = 6, column = 4, sticky = "e")
                        break               
                    else:
                        LABEL = tk.Text(self, width = 30, height = 2, wrap = tk.WORD, foreground = 'red')
                        LABEL.grid(row = 6, column = 3, sticky = "nsew", pady = (0,0), padx = (20,0))
                        LABEL.insert(1.0, "INVENTORY DOES NOT EXIST")
                        LABEL.configure(state = 'disabled')
        DATE_Search_label = tk.Label(self, text = "Search by DATE", font = ("Helvetica", 9))
        DATE_Search_label.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        DATE_Search_Entry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = DATE_VAR)
        DATE_Search_Entry.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = 2)
        DATE_SEARCH_BUTTON = ttk.Button(self, text = "Search", command = DATE_SEARCH)
        DATE_SEARCH_BUTTON.grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")


app = EXAMPLEapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Also I tried the file extension .csv and the same result.

Comment: Is there a reason for the `break` statement? I think this might be the problem.

Comment: I thought the same thing but if i don't place that there to end the for loop the if and else statement both run when i want only one. So that's the reason for the break. Also if i remove the break it will only grab the last line in the text document and if i try to force the search for the other lines i only get the else statement. Same thing happens when I remove the tkinter module and run the code as only python in the interpreter window. Any suggestions you have I'll also try.

Comment: Bryan - i looked into what you said about overlapping widgets, i changed them to separate columns and rows, it fixed what i said about forcing the search for other lines, but it still inserts the else statement. Anyways my main problem is still that it does not print all the lines the user inputs into the entry box. But thanks anyways :D

Comment: At this point I'll even take any reformatting of the script just need an answer to my problem :(

Comment: Hi Kyte. The reason you have not had a complete answer is because you have not provided [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code. Please provide the MCVE and someone (likely myself) is sure to provide you with an adequate answer.

Comment: Updated it, thank you for any input to get it to insert all the lines it finds into the text box.

Comment: I am going to be heading home in a min. When I get home tonight if no one else has answered I will work on updating my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

I have made several changes to your code.

There were way too many emblems with the way you had it set up.

As I am not 100% sure how what you are trying to accomplish I have made progress with your code.

Below is the edited version of your code.
I also created a text file on my end to test with and it seams to have worked so let me know if this is getting close to what you are attempting to do.

A few notes:

1st I moved everything into one class. The way you had it set up was just not going to work without some major changes.

2nd I needed to add `self.` to many of your variables because they are variables that we need to interact with in the class.

3rd I changed they way you get the data from the entry box. The way you were doing it was just not working so I simplified it by adding `.get()` function to the entry variable.

4th but probably should have been the 1st thing I mentions. The way you had your main `Tk()` window starting was odd. I changed how root was created and how we pass it into the class. This seams to make more sense to me.

This is much better to use IMO.

Let me know what parts you still need explanation on and I will make updates to my answer as needed.

Update:

change the while open statement a bit. You do not need to recreate the text box and reconfigure it ever for loop this is not good and will prevent you from seeing multiple items. Also I do not believe you can have a multi line label thought I have never tried. Lets change this to a text box this should do what we need.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class EXAMPLEapp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.root.wm_title("TM Duch\'e Nut CO.")
        self.FILE_MENU_BAR()
        self.root.minsize(width = 360, height = 200)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.container.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(6, weight = 0)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight = 0)

        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Search Inventory", font = ("Helvetica", 20, 'bold', 'underline'))
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "nsew", pady = (0,0), padx = (0,0))
        self.button0 = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Inventory Search")
        self.button0.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))     
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "New Inventory", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(CreatePage))
        self.button1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Edit Invetory", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(EditPage))
        self.button2.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))         
        self.button3 = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Ship", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(ShipPage))
        self.button3.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))
        self.button4 = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Graph", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(PlotPage))
        self.button4.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = (0,10))
        self.DATE_Search_label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Search by DATE", font = ("Helvetica", 9))
        self.DATE_Search_label.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")
        self.DATE_Search_Entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.DATE_Search_Entry.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = "nsew", pady = 0, padx = 2)
        self.DATE_SEARCH_BUTTON = ttk.Button(self.root, text = "Search", command = lambda: self.DATE_SEARCH())
        self.DATE_SEARCH_BUTTON.grid(row = 6, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

    def DATE_SEARCH(self):
        with open('SAMPLE.txt', 'r') as f:
            search_f = f.readlines()
            self.text = tk.Text(self.root, width = 30, height = 2)
            self.text.grid(row = 6, column = 3, sticky = "ew", pady = (0,0), padx = (20,0))
            self.ScrollBar = tk.Scrollbar(self.root)
            self.ScrollBar.config(command = self.text.yview)
            self.text.config(yscrollcommand = self.ScrollBar.set)
            self.ScrollBar.grid(row = 6, column = 4, sticky = "ns")
            self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")

            USER_TEXT = self.DATE_Search_Entry.get()
            if USER_TEXT == '':
                self.text.config(foreground = 'red')
                self.text.insert(tk.END, "PLEASE ENTER A VALUE")
            else:
                match_in_file = False
                for line in search_f:
                    if USER_TEXT in line:
                        self.text.config(foreground = 'black')
                        self.text.insert(tk.END, "{}".format(line))
                        match_in_file = True
                if match_in_file == False:
                    self.text.config(foreground = 'red')
                    self.text.insert(tk.END, "INVENTORY DOES NOT EXIST")


    def FILE_MENU_BAR(self):
        #File
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self.root)
        self.root.config(menu = self.menu)
        self.fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff = 0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = self.fileMenu)
        self.fileMenu.add_separator()
        self.fileMenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = lambda: self.root.destroy())
        # Edit Menu
        self.Edit_Menu = tk.Menu(self.menu)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label = "Edit", menu = self.Edit_Menu)
        self.Edit_Menu.add_command(label = "cut", underline = 2, command = self.Edit_Cut)
        self.Edit_Menu.add_command(label = "copy", underline = 0, command = self.Edit_Copy)  

    def File_EXIT(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def Edit_Cut(self):
        print("CUT")

    def Edit_Copy(self):
        print("COPY")

root = tk.Tk()
app = EXAMPLEapp(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's only part of the problem. They are also stacking a bunch of text widgets (one per match) in the same row and column

Comment: oh I see that in the for loop. I will have to review my answer in a bit I am not available to update my answer right now.

Comment: @Kyte: Hey I just updated my answer. Give it a look and let me know if it helps.

Comment: This way also works but I'm still having an issue where I have it self.LABEL.insert(1.0, line)  it will only insert the first line the word falls on and not all of them. Like for example if I type in the year 2013 I have 6 entries in the text document but it only grabs the first one it sees. I really appreciate the prompt feed back though! Anything you add is a great help for me!

Comment: @Kyte: I made some changes let me know if it helps

Comment: Dude I owe you a damn beer! Thank you that's exactly what I wanted! I changed my format a bit to match the building a text box once and then I dropped all the self. stuff I didn't need it but now it works, you my friend are awesome! But I still have an issue with when I search it puts the else statement into the text box with the results also it prints it 5 times in a row also I need the text to be red only for the if and else statements. you can use the code you provided so far to make changes. Again thank you so much! Also if you cant help anymore I understand.

Comment: @Kyte: I made the needed changes to do what you described in your comment. Let me know if it helps

Comment: Now I owe you a 6 pack. Its perfect thank you so much! I've got my answer I've been searching so long for, THANK YOU!

Comment: @Kyte: Well if you are satisfied then consider selecting the check box next the my answer. Glad to be able to help.